# gvim What do the @ symbols mean at the bottom left of the screen?

Tags: vim

I've been getting used to using vim for the last two weeks and am really starting to like it. There's one thing I've been wondering about - sometimes when I'm typing something, these rows with nothing but the @ symbol appear at the bottom of the screen:

[image: Screenshot of vim notes I was taking when I noticed this - 2 @ rows at bottom of the screen]

This has happened a couple of times but I've never paid much attention to it, but I'm curious - like in that situation, pressing enter gets rid of one of them, and pressing enter again gets rid of the other. Then another two enters after that, another @ row appears. Does anyone know what they mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this usually happens when you open a very big file (or very long lines).

You can set `display` option to show all lines. (without showing those `@`).

```
lastline    When included, as much as possible of the last line
        in a window will be displayed.  When not included, a
        last line that doesn't fit is replaced with "@" lines.
```

e.g. in my vimrc, I have `set display=lastline`

if you want to know detail about it, check `:h 'display'`

Comment: Oh... that makes sense! Cheers for that; it's one of those questions that's quite hard to describe to google!

Answer (score 6):

This means you have a line larger than your terminal's height and width.